# Single-Field Exemption in Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

We did a clickops to add a single-field exemption for Array contains in Firestore.
Im wondering how this can be set using python or Terraform code?
[image]

```
CollectionID = 'srcs'
fieldpath = '*'
```

tried this code but no luck:

```
 
            "fieldOverrides": [
                                    {
                                    "collection": "srcs",
                                    "fieldPath": "*",
                                    "indexes": [
                                                {
                                                    "array_config": "CONTAINS",
                                                    "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
                                                }
                                            ]

                                    }
                            ] 
                            
            }
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#use_terraform)?

Comment: yes, that one is to create a terraform index but not index exemption. I want the array contains to get bypassed. i think Terraform cant do it. I can do it via click ops. But would like to have as a code for deployment

Comment: do you know how to run the fieldOverrides above without using Firestore CLI?